# Parallel processes in distributed tensorflow

Tags: session, parallel-processing, tensorflow, distributed, reinforcement-learning

I have neural network in tensorflow with trained parameters, it is "policy" for agent. Network is being updated in training loop in main tensorflow session in core program.

In the end of each training cycle I need to pass this network to few parallel processes ("workers"), which will use it for collecting samples from interactions of agent's policy with environment.

I need to do it in parallel, because simulating environment takes most of the time and runs only single-core. So, few parallel sampling processes are needed. I am struggling how to structure this in distributed tensorflow. What I considered so far:

1. Create main session in core program, where global network is updated.
   Spawn processes with python multiprocessing and pass them network's global parameters (can I just pass network as an argument?). Then in each process separate Session is created, where network runs.

Minimal example for this is here (also inserted code below): 
https://gist.github.com/dd210/e1808efcc4362cab949ad0337ba600a9

Problem with this example that it sometimes hangs on sess.run in 2nd process. And sometimes it runs smoothly (!). So, there got to be some fundamental issue with this approach..
In my real code 2nd agent just always hangs on sess.run.

2. Somehow use between-graph replication and Supervisor (for managing sessions) in order to create one master session (in core program) and use replicas of global network on the workers.
   Seems more accurate, but here I don't know how to structure it. Example of code from official tutorial is quite different.

Would be grateful for advice.

Code to p.1:

```
import time
import tensorflow as tf

from multiprocessing import Process

N_WORKERS = 2
SPEC = {'worker': ['127.0.0.1:12824', '127.0.0.1:12825']}

def run_worker(task):
    spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec(SPEC)
    server = tf.train.Server(spec, job_name='worker', task_index=task)
    sess = tf.Session(server.target)
    x = tf.Variable(0., dtype=tf.float32, name='x')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print 'result: ', sess.run(x)

def main(_):
    workers = []
    for i in xrange(2):
        p = Process(target=run_worker, args=(i,))
        p.start()
        workers.append(p)
        time.sleep(1)
    for w in workers: w.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Check out the code in https://github.com/openai/universe-starter-agent , is does exactly that (ie, runs multiple atari environments in different processes and learns from them)

Comment: BTW, TensorFlow is somewhat incompatible with multiprocessing, this hanging behavior is common when combing them

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes, I saw this agent (A3C) and used it with python Process, but it is a bit different. In A3C, all processes are independent and run in parallel from the beginning. They only sync from time to time with global parameter network, but in general they all do the same (collecting samples, calc grads). I mean another scenario, when there are two steps in training loop: a) Collecting samples from N workers, b) Calc opt step on the basis of samples, then repeat a) and b). Or do you mean that I can put all the calculations from b) on one "master" worker with some kind of "barrier"?

Comment: so if the workers don't need TensorFlow, you could use multiprocessing for them, and then use ZMQ to send observations to another process which runs them through tensorflow

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov They need it, because workers are basically agents that interacts with environment. But calculation of optimal action with tensorflow in this case is not a bottleneck (env simulator is), so that's why parallel processes are needed. And another question -- you mentioned that TF is "somewhat imcompatible" with multiprocessing, does that mean that I can avoid "hanging behaviour" if I just replace Process with subprocess.Popen?

Comment: yes, that should work. The problem with multiprocessing is that it calls `fork`, and TensorFlow may have global state that's incompatible with forking

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you very much! Guess p.1 from my question doesn't make much sense now. I will think how to structure p.2 better.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov With regards to multiprocessing. I found this github issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5448) where someone recommend to make processes daemon to avoid hanging sessions. It appeared to help in my case, or I just got lucky. Do you know, is it a real fix or some unexpected behavior?